# How do I make a section of my UIView a clickable area

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to make a certain section of my UIView clickable. When clicked, it triggers an IBAction, as would an UIButton.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [`UITapGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to your `UIView`. When you receive a tap, check your recognizer's `locationInView:`. Trigger the action if the tap happened in the area that you would like to make tap-sensitive; otherwise, ignore the tap event.

Comment: You can also simply place a transparent button over the area, if you don't need to resolve the precise position.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks Hot Licks and dasblinkenlight!

Comment: I just implemented the transparent button, works perfectly! Also enabling "hidden" whenever I don't want it clickable.

Answer (score 3):

Add Custom UIButton on your view, what ever position you need to clickable, Then perform 
action on it.

```
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:0];
    [button setFrame:CGRectmake(0,0,0,0)]; //What ever clickable area, provide here
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 2):

Using UITapGestureRecognizer  and put transparent  button over the area where you want clickable section available